# Web Api dangerous request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I have a simple Web Api controller, which has been set up as follows:

```
 [Authorize]
 [RoutePrefix("api/messageDetail")]
 public class MessageDetailController : ApiController
 {
    [Route("{messageId}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMessageDetail(string messageId)
    {
        var result = MtFacade.GetAmlResults(messageId);

        var results = new List<string>();

        results.AddRange(result.Select(item => ((AmlResults) item).Result));

        return messageId == null ?   Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No messageId provided") : Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
    }
  }
```

Can someone assist me with URLEncoding the param being passed in, as its causing 'A Potentially dangerous Reuqest' when passing in something like this:

> servername.sometext.1.:3/0

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman has a great write-up on this problem (and some solutions): http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: Hi Cavincn, great article, but i'm tempted to steer clear of turning things off. Supporting something in future and all that.